# PHP if variable isset set id to value1 else set to value2

Tags: php

On a page I have form with the following inputs:

```
<input class="half" type="text" name="tourney" placeholder="BRDTNS16">
<select class="half" name="tourneydrop">
    <option value="">--------</option>
    <option value="BRDTNS16">Bordtennis</option>
    <option value="SMSHBR16">Smash Bros</option>
    <option value="MROKRT16">Mario Kart</option>
    <option value="GEKOUT16">Geek out</option>
    <option value="HRTSTN16">Hearthstone</option>
</select>
```

I want to override `tourney` if `tourneydrop` is set, I do this using the following code

```
if (isset($_POST['tourneydrop'])) {
    $id = $_POST['tourneydrop'];
}
else {
    $id = $_POST['tourney'];
}
```

But this is not working as intended and leaves the `$id` empty no matter what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because, if `tourneydrop` is not set, then it should set `$id` to `tourney`, yet `tourney` has no value. Give it a value with

```
<input value="abc">
```

When `tourneydrop` is set, however, it can be set of a value of `value=""`.

Comment: I changed default value of tourneydrop to be N and then changed the PHP to


    `if ($_POST['tourneydrop'] == "N") {

        $id = $_POST['tourney'];

    } else {

        $id = $_POST['tourneydrop'];

    }`

Comment: Then you should also add a `selected` to the the default value of tourneydrop.